# Thrift/Proto How to?

Tags: c#, serialization, buffer, protocol-buffers, thrift

I need to serialize a large array of object of 100000 to a file, but during de-serialization I would like to read chuck of 1000 objects per read.

Currently I don't find any good examples of either Thrift or Protocol Buffer for C#. Please can someone help me out.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Well protobuf-csharp-port has [`MessageStreamIterator`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/source/browse/src/ProtocolBuffers/MessageStreamIterator.cs) and [`MessageStreamWriter`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/source/browse/src/ProtocolBuffers/MessageStreamWriter.cs) which allow you to write out a sequence and then iterate over them as you deserialize. Then you can use LINQ to Objects to get 1000 or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use protobuf-net, there is a method DeserializeItems (or similar) that provides an `IEnumerable<T>` implementation, non-buffered, allowing you to consume items as you like (suitable for LINQ "Take" etc). This works perfectly if the original serialized object is a list/array of objects. It is also fully compatible with the DeserializeWithLengthPrefix method, which reads a single object from a stream without over-reading (as log as it is length-prefixed, which **is the case** if an array/list of items is serialized), allowing you to do the same thing in, say, a "while" loop. Let me know if you want more complete examples.

Example:

```
// write
YourType[] array = ...;
Serializer.Serialize(destination, array);

// read
List<YourType> batch = new List<YourType>(1000);
foreach(var item in Serializer.DeserializeItems<YourType>(source)) {
    batch.Add(item);
    if(batch.Count == 1000) {
        ProcessBatch(batch);
        batch.Clear();
    }
}
if(batch.Count != 0) ProcessBatch(batch);
```

Note also that protocol buffers is appendable, so to add more data to a file you just seek to the end of the file and start writing more data.

Comment: Are our two solutions compatible with each other, out of interest?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, it will be great if you can provide complete example.

Comment: @Jon mine is, per item: an **optional** tag as varint, typically "1", then the length as varint, then the payload. Is that compatible?

Comment: @user1261267 no problem - I'm on mobile currently; can add full/tested example later, but rough estimate added

Comment: @Jon oops, I meant "tag decorated as a string wire-type", and note that it also supports big/little-endian 4-byte int length prefix (without tag/wire-type), as lots of people seem to use that.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Possibly. Mine basically embeds each message as if it's a field tag 1 within another message, which sounds like it should be compatible :)

Comment: @Jon yes that is exactly what I do here by default; seems the obvious approach.

Comment: @Marc: I tried The serialize object count is 145867 where as de-serialize count is 0 <br> `int i=0;
foreach (var p in personList)
{
     Serializer.Serialize<PersonName>(protofs, p);
     i++;
}
Console.WriteLine("Total items serialize " + i);
protofs.Flush();
protofs.Close();

protofs = new FileStream(outfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
         i = 0;
            foreach (var p in Serializer.DeserializeItems<PersonName>(protofs, PrefixStyle.None, 0))
            {
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total items deserialize " + i);`

Comment: Serializer.DeserializeItems<T>(FileStream,PrefixStyle,int), which takes three arguments, where as your example shows single argument.<br/> <code> 
protofs = new FileStream(outfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
int i = 0;          
foreach(var p in Serializer.DeserializeItems<PersonName>(protofs, PrefixStyle.None, 0)){
                i++;
}
Console.WriteLine(i);</code>

Comment: @user1261267 well, you've used different code so I'm not amazed it didn't work! Use: `Serialize(protofs, list)` for write, and `DeserializeItems<PersonName>(protofs, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1)` for read. If you need to write each item separately, use SerializeWithLengthPrefix specifying Base128 and tag/field=1